# Using identify and attach in a function

Tags: r

I want to identify data on a plot after using attach(), but I have the problem to detach before exiting my function:

```
f = function(x, y, data) {
  attach(data)
  plot(x, y)
  ids = identify(x, y)
  detach(data)
  return ids
}
```

The returned value:

```
<environment: 0xf785ed8>
attr(,"name")
[1] "data"
> class(i1)
[1] "environment"
> str(i1)
<environment: 0xf785ed8> 
 - attr(*, "name")= chr "data"
```

How can I use attach and identify in a function and return the ids of the attached object?

Comment: Not sure if this is the source of your problem, but `return ids` should be `return(ids)`.

Comment: What if you just avoided the `attach` / `detach` altogether?

Comment: @docendodiscimus Then how do I evaluate x and y (they are data names)?

Comment: A reproducible example would be pretty useful in such a case.

Comment: return(ids) does fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to do non-standard evaluation here.  This is always a little tricky.  Can I recommend something like:

```
f <- function(x, y, data) {
    dx <- deparse(substitute(x))
    dy <- deparse(substitute(y))
    plot(reformulate(dx,response=dy),data)
    ids <- identify(data[,dx], data[,dy])
    return(ids)
}
f(Population,Income,state.x77)
```

or

```
f2 <- function(x, y, data) {
    x <- eval(substitute(x),envir=as.data.frame(data))
    y <- eval(substitute(y),envir=as.data.frame(data))
    plot(x,y)
    ids <- identify(x,y)
    return(ids)
}
f2(Population,Income,state.x77)
```

You might want to look at [Hadley Wickham's notes on non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) for more information ...

Comment: ok. There are many library functions in R taking a data frame and variable names, as separate parameters, like lm(). I find this function call syntax easier to use and was trying to replicate the same convention in my function.